# Gradle local dependencies are not visible

Tags: java, gradle

In my project I use some local dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('lib/mylib.jar')
}
```

Why when I call `gradle dependencies` I can't see this library as a dependency? Command `gradle dependencies --configuration compile` returns this:

```
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
No dependencies
```

Dependencies downloaded from repository (maven/ivy) are visible. For example:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
}
```

will show:

```
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I should also add that dependencies are not shown but project compiles properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle documentation on [file dependency](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#file-dependencies) explains

> File dependencies are **not included in the published dependency descriptor** for your project. However, file dependencies are included in transitive project dependencies within the same build. This means they cannot be used outside the current build, but they can be used with the same build.

Comment: Bad news :/ Is there some other possibility to show local dependencies (excluding creating new task which will list all files)?

Comment: Also see this [issue](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1332) in the Gradle JIRA tracker.

Answer (score -1):

Use api(name: 'mylib', ext: 'jar') as a workaround.